# Why are 8 points needed to compute a fundamental matrix?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, stereo-vision

[Homograpies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography#Geometric_motivation) have 8 degrees of freedom.
[Fundamental matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_matrix_(computer_vision)) have 7.
[Essential matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_matrix) have 5.

To the best I could find, all those matrices are obtained by using [the 8 point algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight-point_algorithm).

I don't see why the fundamental and essential matrices can't make do with less points.

Please enlighten me

Answer (score 1):

Hum, no

- A homography can be exactly fit to 4 point such that no three of them are collinear (example [implementation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga4abc2ece9fab9398f2e560d53c8c9780) in OpenCv).
- An essential matrix can be fit to the image of 5 non-coplanar points ([implementation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga0c86f6478f36d5be6e450751bbf4fec0)).
- A fundamental matrix can be fit to 7 points ([implementation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gae420abc34eaa03d0c6a67359609d8429))

Answer (score 1):

They can. As Francesco mentioned, these problems can be solved with less correspondences. What makes the difference is how we formulate the problem.

If we like a fast linear solution, then 8-points are required. For formulations using less number of points, the constraints are non-linear and typically involve either determinants or systems of polynomial equations that are solved with some form of Gröbner basis methods. These methods are typically known under the name *minimal problems in computer vision* and are investigated heavily by Zuzana Kukelova. For a set of related problems and proposed solutions refer to the website: http://aag.ciirc.cvut.cz/minimal/.

**For the particular case of 8-point algorithm**: In the 8-point algorithm we solve (in a linear fashion) for the elements of a matrix that is not necessarily a fundamental/essential matrix. In a subsequent step, we then project this matrix onto the manifold of essential matrices. This is how we obtain the end result. That stage ensures two non-linear constraints:
$$
\begin{align}
\det\mathbf{E} &= 0\\
2\mathbf{E}\mathbf{E}^{\top}\mathbf{E}-\text{tr}(\mathbf{E}\mathbf{E}^{\top})\mathbf{E} &= 0
\end{align}
$$
So not every matrix is an essential matrix and we cannot simply have $0$s for certain terms.

You see here that the solution to the initial linear system is subject to a different constraint which can yield a linear system. If we like to bake the actual non-linear constraints in, we can reduce the number of points to 5 (for essential) at the cost of increased complexity.

Comment: Thanks! Why don't less points firmulate just tge same linear equations? Why aren't less than 8 enough?

Comment: Updated my reply.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. In the 8 point algorithm, we are solving for [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,1], so why not for example just solve the same way for [a,b,c,0,e,f,0,0,1] (matrices in vec form)?

Comment: I think this just creates more numerical problems. Because we then need to project the final E onto the essential manifold, but having 0s there creates a quite far matrix. The projection is not very meaningful then, right?

Comment: I…  don't see why it won't be meaningful. If you could show where exactly the algorithm would fail if you plug in zeros, i would be very happy

Comment: Updated the reply again. if you simply leave $0$s it is not an essential matrix. We have to post-enforce the constraints.

Comment: The link don't work here

Comment: Sorry about that. It's still the official webpage. I hope it gets fixed at some point.

Comment: Link for the minimal problems is updated.

Answer (score -1):

F has seven degrees of freedom: a 3×3 homogeneous matrix has eight independent ratios (there are nine elements, and the common scaling is not signifificant);
however, F also satisfifies the constraint det F = 0 which removes one degree of freedom ---- From Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision (Second Edition, P 246)

There exists a algorithm for computing F from 7 points - but it is quite a bit more complex that the one for 8 points. Thus, the 8-point algorithm is a good and common baseline for computing F. Explanations From here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z92eUJjIJeY&lc=UgxEqBefD5oDdDFxzVt4AaABAg.9f_s5HWZe3r9fav49ZOwqR

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: Lake_Lagunita: Please elaborate on why you think this answer's @Gulzar's question.

Comment: There exists a algorithm for computing F from 7 points - but it is quite a bit more complex that the one for 8 points. Thus, the 8-point algorithm is a good and common baseline for computing F.  Explanations From here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z92eUJjIJeY&lc=UgxEqBefD5oDdDFxzVt4AaABAg.9f_s5HWZe3r9fav49ZOwqR

Comment: Please edit your answer to add this extra info.